# linq where clause using containsAll

Tags: c#, linq

How can I query an object using LINQ to check whether the object contains all elements in an array or not.

```
from p in product
where p.keywords.ContainsAll( keyword )
select p
```

I mean containsAll not containsAny. Is this possible?

Comment: Please make an effort at writing your question down. Even if it's not your first, second or third language you can still assume that the first 5 words in a sentence don't need uppercase.

Comment: Is this linq to objects, or using a query provider?  If it's a query provider, which is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.All` in `Where`. In `All` you use `array.Contains`.

```
var productWithAllKeyWords = product
    .Where(p => p.keywords.All(pk => keywords.Contains(pk)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var containsAll = keyword.Except(p.keywords).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need a function that checks if List a is a **subset** of list b.

You can use the following function

```
public static bool ContainsAll(List<T> a, List<T> b)
{
   return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

Or

```
from p in product
where ContainsAll(p.keywords,keyword)
select p
```

Hope this will help you!